# NodeJS require('..')?

Tags: node.js, require

I've been looking through some NodeJS examples and I've encountered the following:

```
var module = require('..');
var module = require('../');
```

I understand what require does, but I don't understand what it does when it's written like this. Can somebody explain it to me please?

Comment: Could you provide me github examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rule defined in https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

> require(X) from module at path Y
>
> 2. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
>      a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
>      b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)

Since `../` or `..` is not a file, it will go to path B, to load as directory

> LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
>
> 1. If X/package.json is a file,
>      a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
>      b. let M = X + (json main field)
>      c.
>      LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
> 2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
> 3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
> 4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP

By that rule, it will check the following files in this order

1) `../package.json`

2) `../index.js`

3) `../index.json`

4) `../index.node`

Comment: hi. i'm wondering. what is it happening when i do like this. please see this repo (https://github.com/MJB-Khorasani/require) and answer me. thanks. in admin.js file & user.js file it does not know express. but i import it in imports.js file. so what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you require a directory, [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) will try to include a module from that directory based on these rules:

> If X/package.json is a file,
>       a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
>       b. let M = X + (json main field)
>       c. LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
>   2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
>   3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
>   4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP

Most likely you have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
module/
  index.js
  src/
    file-including.js
```

This will load `index.js`. You could also write it as `require('../index.js')` or even `require('../index')` and it would function the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var module = require('..');` and `var module = require('../');` results the same.

Both loaded from the parent directory.

Comment: hi. i'm wondering. what is it happening when i do like this. please see this repo (github.com/MJB-Khorasani/require) and answer me. thanks. in admin.js file & user.js file it does not know express. but i import it in imports.js file. so what's wrong with this?